# Set method to be called by Express.js as param

Tags: node.js, express

When using Express normally you use `app.post('/path')` or `app.get('/path')` to define routes.

Does Express also provide a function to define routes like this `app.route('POST', '/path')` (where `route` is the function I'm looking for)?

Comment: Can I ask what do you try to achieve with it?

Comment: I want to register routes programmatically

Comment: Do you try `app['post']`?

Comment: How would the complete declaration look like (including path etc)? How would I set multiply routes using `POST` this way?

Comment: It will be `app['post']('/path')`, `app['post']('/path-2')` ...

Comment: Tried, it and it seems to work.

Comment: So if my suggestion is correct, I will add a new answer and can you tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can programmatically select method with bracket notation. For example:

```
app['post']('/path')
app['post']('/path-2')
app['get']('/path')
```